# Get next trading day using pandas market calendar

Tags: python, pandas, date

I would like to modify the code below so that I can get the trading days n days from now or n days ago:

```
import pandas_market_calendars as mcal
holidays = nyse.holidays()
mydate = pd.to_datetime("12/24/2019")
holidays(mydate)
Timestamp('2019-12-26 00:00:00')
```

Is there a way to provide the number of days as an argument to holidays()?

I can get this to work with Federal holidays like so:

```
from pandas.tseries.holiday import USFederalHolidayCalendar
bday_us1 = CustomBusinessDay(calendar=USFederalHolidayCalendar(), n=2)
mydate + bday_us1
Timestamp('2019-12-27 00:00:00')
```

Answer (score 4):

I will assume you have this line in there somewhere already:

```
nyse = mcal.get_calendar('NYSE')
```

What you might be looking for is something like this:

```
nyse.valid_days(start_date='2016-12-20', end_date='2017-01-10')
```

This returns a list of all valid dates (non-holidays) withing the start and end dates.
To get this date range:

```
mydate = pd.to_datetime("12/24/2019")
d = datetime.timedelta(days = 10)
start_date = mydate - d
end_date = mydate + d
```

Comment: Thanks Garrett. I am not sure how your d variable takes into account the mcal calendar? It simply increases/decreases the days right?

Comment: yes, just showing how to get a start_date and end_date. Could be done in a variety of ways.

Comment: My goal is more to increase the date taking into account holidays, so if there is a holiday on the next day skip to the next trading day.

Comment: Then just iterate over the list of all valid days for whatever your total date range is.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for in trying to find market trading days including holidays. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution that works, I simply use the date of valid trading days inside of my function, instead of the holidays:

```
def next_business_day(start_day, business_days, HOLIDAYS):
    ONE_DAY = datetime.timedelta(days=1)
    temp_day = start_day
    for i in range(0, business_days):
        next_day = temp_day + ONE_DAY
        while next_day.weekday() in [5,6] or next_day not in nyse.valid_days(start_date='2000-12-20', end_date='2020-01-10'):
            next_day += ONE_DAY
        temp_day = next_day
    return temp_day
```

Note this is based on a post from a different forum, where the holidays were used instead:

```
def next_business_day(start_day, business_days, HOLIDAYS):
    ONE_DAY = datetime.timedelta(days=1)
    temp_day = start_day
    for i in range(0, business_days):
        next_day = temp_day + ONE_DAY
        while next_day.weekday() in [5,6] or next_day in HOLIDAYS:
            next_day += ONE_DAY
        temp_day = next_day
    return temp_day
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no `holidays` method that takes a date range. Taking the current date as a basis, we can generate a list of dates containing 5 days ahead and 5 days ago. Then for each day we collect the next holiday into a `set` in order to avoid duplicates. Optionally we sort the `list` obtained because `set` does not maintain order.

```
import pandas_market_calendars as mcal
import pandas as pd
from datetime import timedelta

mydate = pd.to_datetime("12/24/2019")
nyse = mcal.get_calendar('NYSE')
holidays = nyse.holidays()

delta = timedelta(5)
start = mydate - delta
end = mydate + delta

date_list = [end - (timedelta(x)) for x in range((end-start).days)]
holidays = list(set(holidays(d) for d in date_list))
for day in sorted(holidays):
    print(day)
```

Output

```
2019-12-23 00:00:00
2019-12-24 00:00:00
2019-12-26 00:00:00
2019-12-27 00:00:00
2019-12-30 00:00:00
```

Comment: I have edited my original post, see above to show what I am trying to achieve with USFederalHolidayCalendar, which works.